# Is it possible to simplify a query with multiple joins to the same table?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, join

I have a rather large query which takes longer to run than I would like because of 17 `LEFT JOIN`s on the same table. I've done some searching, but haven't found anything that is really similar to my situation. I am just wondering if it is possible to simplify (and speed up) this portion of the query.

I'm looking at the portion of `LEFT JOIN`s that I've padded with extra lines, but I would generally be accepting of any improvement suggestions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbDivision.DivisionNum                       AS DivisionNum,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.Subdivision         AS Subdivision,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.ClientUserLastName  AS AgentLastName,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.ClientUserFirstName AS AgentFirstName,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.Rank                AS Rank,
                tbClient.VisitDate                           AS VisitDate,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.FirstName           AS BuyerFirstName,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.LastName            AS BuyerLastName,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.Address1            AS Address1,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.Address2            AS Address2,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.City                AS City,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.State               AS State,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.Country             AS Country,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.Zip                 AS Zip,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.WorkPhone           AS WorkPhone,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.WorkExt             AS WorkExt,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.HomePhone           AS HomePhone,
                vuBSBuyers.MobilePhone                       AS MobilePhone,
                vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.Email               AS Email,
                vuGetRealtorByClientID.FirstName             AS RealtorFirstName,
                vuGetRealtorByClientID.LastName              AS RealtorLastName,
                vuGetRealtorByClientID.JobPosition           AS Position,
                vuGetRealtorByClientID.CompanyName           AS Realty,
                COI.Description                              AS CommunityOfInterest,
                CASE
                  WHEN tbClient.VisitDate >= '2015-01-01'
                  THEN TimeNew.Description
                  ELSE TimeOld.Description
                END                                          AS TimeFrame,
                CASE
                  WHEN tbClient.VisitDate >= '2015-01-01'
                  THEN PriceNew.Description
                  ELSE PriceOld.Description
                END                                          AS PriceRange,
                LS1.Description                              AS LS1,
                LS2.Description                              AS LS2,
                CASE
                  WHEN tbClient.VisitDate >= '2015-01-01'
                  THEN TypeNew.Description
                  ELSE TypeOld.Description
                END                                          AS HomeType,
                CASE
                  WHEN tbClient.VisitDate >= '2015-01-01'
                  THEN SqFtNew.Description
                  ELSE SqFtOld.Description
                END                                          AS SqFootage,
                CASE
                  WHEN tbClient.VisitDate >= '2015-01-01'
                    THEN Feature.Description
                    ELSE
                     CASE
                       WHEN Golf.Description LIKE 'Yes%' OR Golf.Description LIKE 'Somewhat%' THEN 'Golf'
                       WHEN Gated.Description LIKE 'Yes%' OR Gated.Description LIKE 'Somewhat%' THEN 'Gated/Security'
                     END
                END                                  AS ImportantFeatures,
                CASE
                  WHEN tbClient.VisitDate >= '2015-01-01'
                  THEN AgeNew.Description
                  ELSE AgeOld.Description
                END                                          AS AgeRange,
                FCL.Description AS [Future Community List]

FROM tbDivision
     INNER JOIN tbSubdivision ON tbDivision.ID = tbSubdivision.DivisionID
     INNER JOIN vuRptProspectsAgentLevel ON tbSubdivision.ID = vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.SubdivisionID
     INNER JOIN tbClient ON vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.ID = tbClient.ID
     LEFT JOIN vuGetRealtorByClientID ON tbClient.ID = vuGetRealtorByClientID.ClientID
     LEFT JOIN tbMember ON tbClient.ID = tbMember.ClientID
     LEFT JOIN vuBSBuyers ON tbMember.ID = vuBSBuyers.ID

     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS LS1 ON tbClient.Demo1ID = LS1.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS LS2 ON tbClient.Demo2ID = LS2.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS TypeOld ON tbClient.Demo25ID = TypeOld.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS TypeNew ON tbClient.Demo5ID = TypeNew.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS AgeOld ON tbClient.Demo17ID = AgeOld.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS AgeNew ON tbClient.Demo8ID = AgeNew.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS SqFtOld ON tbClient.Demo28ID = SqFtOld.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS SqFtNew ON tbClient.Demo10ID = SqFtNew.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS TimeOld ON tbClient.Demo26ID = TimeOld.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS TimeNew ON tbClient.Demo12ID = TimeNew.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS PriceOld ON tbClient.Demo29ID = PriceOld.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS PriceNew ON tbClient.Demo13ID = PriceNew.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS Feature ON tbClient.Demo14ID = Feature.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS COI ON tbClient.Demo16ID = COI.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS FCL ON tbClient.Demo24ID = FCL.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS Golf ON tbClient.Demo30ID = Golf.ID
     LEFT JOIN tbDatacodesSubdiv AS Gated ON tbClient.Demo32ID = Gated.ID

WHERE vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.Rank IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'H Hold') AND
    vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.ClientUserID NOT IN (1, 319, 342) AND
      vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.Status = 'prospect'

ORDER BY tbDivision.DivisionNum,
         vuRptProspectsAgentLevel.Subdivision
```

Comment: Why does the table `Client` has a gazillion of `demoXXid` ?

Comment: I don't have control over the schema, so I cannot tell you. I'm working with what I got! :)

Comment: Can you provide the execution plan? And what is the need of the `DISTINCT`? That is often a performance break (especially after 17 joins!)

Comment: Post an execution plan!

Comment: How? SQL Server only does the flowchart thing, not exactly copy and pastable.

Comment: That flowcharty thing should be your close friend. Especially in SSMS if you right click the query and choose 'Show actual execution plan.' Reviewing it to show where the costly joins can help identify why your query is performing badly.  You should be able to right click and save it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your query goes, it seems you've followed SQL best practices so there are no easy, significant performance boosts I could find. Now, sorry to state the obvious, but make sure you have enough indexes and that you are using those indexes, and check if all your stats are up to date. Database Engine Tuning Advisor is a great tool to check both of those.

Now, perhaps this is unconventional, but I have to ask how often does this data change and do you always need the most up to date version? If the data only changes once in a while and it's not imperative that you have the latest data, you could store this query in physical table and update it every day or whatever time period you choose OR you could have triggers on each underlying table that execute a stored procedure that updates your table every time the data changes. 
**Note:** this is only practical if the data does not change often.